# C++ - a more efficient way to address a list inside loop argument

Tags: c++, list, while-loop, arguments

As title says. For example you have a list of values char values[11] and you want to cycle through that list inside the loop argument:

```
while(something not in values[])
{
    doSomething(omgwtfbbq)
}
```

But of course it does not work in C++... or so I think. At least the 'not' keyword does not exist.

Can anyone suggest if there is a solvent for this?

Comment: technically `not` is not a **keyword** but a **reseved identifier** in C++. however, that distinction is very subtle. for a compiler that does not let you use `not` directly, try including the `<iso646.h>` header (such a compiler is non-conforming, however: standard C++ requires support for `not` without using that header)

Comment: I included <iso646.h> and tried to use:

while (something not in values[])

but not is hilighted as not defined. Though it is now recognised.

Yes, I can't get it working. I have quite limited knowledge of C++ as of yet.

Comment: are you sure you need `while(something not in values[])` and not `if(something not in values[])`?

Comment: ^ I am trying to write an error check in a console application. So the logic, realistically requires a loop:

while user has not entered the value from the list => continue cycling the loop until an acceptable value has been entered.

But if you happen to suggest an alternative without using the above way, but with the same effect, I will be happy to accept it.

Comment: `while (std::find(&values[0], &values[11], something) == values[11]) {...}`. More readable if you say `int *first = &values[0]; int *last = &values[11]` first, then you can say `while (std::find(first, last, something) == last)`. [It took me a while to figure out what you were trying to do. At first, I thought you wanted `something` to enumerate all integers that aren't in `values`...]

Comment: ^ok. I'll try this too. I just broke my program completely, so it'll take a while :D

Comment: @RaymondChen, I succeeded in doing it your way. I changed the list into a vector to remove the confusing syntax, and used the find() function you suggested and it now works. Thanks!

Can you make an answer out of your comment, so I can accept it?

Comment: @Alf - `not` is neither a keyword or `reserved identifier`, if we're going to be pedantic. It is an alternative token, as defined by §2.6 P2.

Comment: @RaymondChen `while something not in vector` indeed looks like trying to enumerate all such values, especially if you're familiar with Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the problem was solved, but the person who answered me in comments did not post a full reply, so I'll post the answer here.

Changed the list to a vector `vector<char> values[4]`. Then used the find function suggested by Raymond Chen:

```
while(find(values.begin(),values.end(),something)==values.end())
{
    doSomething(eatBananas)
}
```

In case Raymond Chen posts an explicit answer, I'll mark his.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the way suggested by @Deepu but a cleaner and more robust solution would be to use events mechanism that exists in your system. On one thread you would wait for *required-key-pressed* event and on another you will intercept the key pressing interrupt and analyze the data. If it contains the required value(s), indicate the *required-key-pressed* event.

Comment: em... ok. I don't completely understand what you are saying here. This sounds something a GUI program would use, which are event-driven. But a console application? depending on circumstances, the user is presented with a different number of possible 'correct' answers.

Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: Nothing limits this to GUI application, it's general approach

Comment: Then I doubt I will be able to implement this in my current state. I don't know about threading and events in console applications.